# how can i display the value on a helper method inside my razor view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have defined the folloiwng helper method inside a model class in my asp.net mvc application:-

```
 public string compnayname(string emailid)
        {
            string name = emailid.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0];
            name = name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1);
            return name;
        }
```

Then on my view i wrote the folloiwng:-

```
<td>
                    @{string v = item.compnayname(item.AaaContactInfo.EMAILID);

                @Html.Display(v.ToString() )}
                </td>
```

But nothing is being displayed on the view ?
so what might be the problem?
BR

Comment: Since the emailid appears to be a member of the same model, you don't need to pass it in as a parameter to a method.  With that, why not turn your method into a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a code block (i.e. the `@{}`). Try using:

`<td>
    @item.companyname(item.AaaContactInfo.EMAILID)
</td>`